# ExoPlayer won't replay video when playback is ended in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I've created an ExoPlayer instance and a button for the user to press if they want the video to be replayed. The button works but only during the playback of the video; when the video completes playback the button no longer works. I have code that runs to show a button when the video completes playback that I think is responsible for breaking this replay button but I can't figure out why!

I run the code below in the `onCreate()` method to make sure that the code is run only once when the Activity is started:

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current

val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .build()
        .also { exoPlayer ->
            val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.xxxxxx))
                    .build()
            exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
            exoPlayer.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
            exoPlayer.addListener(playerEventListener)
            exoPlayer.prepare()
        }

DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(factory = {
            StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
                hideController()
                useController = false
                player = exoPlayer
            }
        })
                ) {
    onDispose { exoPlayer.release() }
}
```

Then here is the code to create the button. This is also run in the `onCreate()` method.

```kotlin
Button(onClick = {                             
                                exoPlayer.seekTo(0)
                                exoPlayer.play() 
                                             }, 
                                  ) {
                                Text(
                                        text = "replay",
                                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                                .padding(5.dp),
                                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                                    )
                            }
```

Now this code works while playback is in progress, but when the video ends the button no longer works and I can just see the final frame of the video.

I've found that this might be something to do with the viewModel method from the method in my `exoPlayer.addListener(playerEventListener)` line:

```kotlin
    private val playerEventListener = object : Player.Listener
    {
        override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int)
        {
            super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
            // when the video ends, make the button to move onto the next page appear
            if (playbackState==ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED)
            {
                viewModel.showNextButton()
            }
        }
    }
```

All the `viewModel.showNextButton()` method does is set a boolean in the viewModel to true (I have a button that gets show when the boolean is set to true so the user can progress when they have watched the whole video). Strangely, removing `viewModel.showNextButton()` from the code solves the issue, but I can't see why setting the boolean to true changes anything?

Below is the code for the viewModel so that you can see the `viewModel.showNextButton()` method:

```kotlin
data class TutorialUiState(
        val showNextButton: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)
                          )

class TutorialViewModel(application: HDiagsApplication) : AndroidViewModel(application)
{
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(TutorialUiState())
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun showNextButton()
    {
        uiState.value.showNextButton.value = true
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I actually raised this issue first on the ExoPlayer repository, the only response I got from them was that it looked like I was creating multiple players and therefore the button to replay the video was running the methods on the wrong player, but I don't think this is the case because everything is done in the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Some thoughts on this issue. It has to be something to do with the change of variable in the viewModel triggering a recomposition when the video ends that causes the exoPlayer to bug out.

Making the `showNextButton()` method empty will allow this code to work, which means that the variable change in the onPlaybackStateChange() method causes a recomposition which breaks the exoPlayer replay button. I'm not sure how to go ahead with this because it seems like it's a library issue to do with it's Jetpack Compose binding.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @latsson yes from what I remember it was because I hadn't put a remember {} around the video player composable, so when the recomposition happened a totally new exoppayer composable was drawn over the top. Hope that solves your issue!

Comment: Nevermind ‍♂️ I forgot to do seekTo(0)